# when trying to create file in unix which has $ in that file it is throwing a number?

Tags: unix, parameterization

trying to create a file with following data using shell script.

**InsertParam.sh**

```
echo "$$Domain=XYZ" >parameter.prm
```

when i run **InsertParam.sh**
Am getting out put as

```
$cat parameter.prm
1979205Domain=XYZ
```

Please help me how to over come this in my **parameter.prm**

i need Data as

```
$$Domain=xyz
```

Comment: Sorry @PaulR for incomplete question. can you help me now. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sh/bash/ksh/zsh`, `$$` is the current PID. see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

You need to use different quotes to prevent that variable from being expanded:

```
echo '$$Domain=XYZ' >parameter.prm
```

see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

---

Quotes can be mixed, as required:

```
echo '$$Domain='"$domain" >parameter.prm
```

Comment: when i use single quotation mark can i use reference variable instead of value. EX  **domain=xyz echo '$$domain=$domain'** so i can change domain name